# Using context menu in Material React Table row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am trying to add context menu for each row of [MUI Table](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/), but I could not see a proper example. Is there a built in support for row level or is it possible to add this feature for per row in MUI Table?

[context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x82xl.jpg)

I tried something but it could not detect the row (I needed to pass the row to another component for editing). So, how should I proceed?

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjj31k?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Hi try to add some context what you tried so others can try to help you out

Comment: the link is a default link ctrl + s to save the stackblitz then add the new link it gives you

Answer (score 0):

To add a context menu to a MUI Table you can capture the context menu handler on the TableRow and pass in the row index. Then you can use this to control a Menu component.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-brook-ld6cn2?file=/src/table.js